# How do I handle toolbar messages in a dialog box

Tags: mfc, dialog, toolbar

I am writing a MFC MDI application, which I started with the wizard, with visual studio 2017. In this application I have dialog boxes with toolbars. But when the dialog boxes are shown, the toolbar buttons are not enabled, even though the dialog classes contain handlers for the button IDs.

For instance, I Created 1 test class for a dialog named CDlg with toolbar with a button with ID ID_DIALOG_1. I have the corresponding message map entry and the corresponding handler function inside CDlg:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_DIALOG_1, &CDlg::OnDialog1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CDlg::ODialog1()
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
}
```

But the toolbar button is disabled.

I experimented putting the handler both inside the document class and CDlg, and in this case the button is enabled and the CDlg::OnDialog1 handler gets called. I also experimented to put a menu on the CDlg class with the ID ID_DIALOG_1 and in this case CDlg::OnDialog1 gets called when the menu item is clicked but the toolbar button remains disabled.

So, Is it possible to have the command handler for the button ID ID_DIALOG_1 inside class CDlg for the toolbar?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I already know that the answer to my question is yes! There was a mistake in my code. I was calling CDialogEx::OnInitDialog() after the creation of the toolbar, but CDialogEx::OnInitDialog() should be called first according to [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/132s802t.aspx#cdialog__oninitdialog)

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in my code. I was calling `CDialogEx::OnInitDialog()` after the creation and loading of toolbar, but actually `CDialogEx::OnInitDialog()` should be called first according to [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/132s802t.aspx#cdialog__oninitdialog).